# equation alignment in a two-column table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

I am having trouble making a table of equations line up properly.

[image: complex table equations]

I would like to align the '=' sign for the Division row, but when I do I end up with something like this:

[image: complex table equationsv2]

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{llll}

    \textrm{Addition}                   & $\left(a+bi \right)+ \left(c+di   \right)=\left(a+c \right) +\left(b+d \right)i   $\\             
    \textrm{Subtraction}                & $\left(a+bi \right)- \left(c+di\right)=\left(a-c \right) +\left(b-d \right)i  $\\             
    \textrm{Multiplication}             & $z*w = r\left(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta \right)* k\left(\cos \psi + i\sin \psi \right)   $\\     
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textrm{Division}}  & &$\frac{z}{w}$    & $= \frac{r(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)}{k(\cos \psi + i \sin \psi)}$ \\
                                        & &               & $= \frac {r}{k} \left[\cos \left(\theta - \psi\right)  +i\sin \left(\theta - \psi\right) \right]$    \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I am using `tabular` because it seemed straight forward. Is it possible to get the desired alignment with `tabular`, or should I be using a different package or environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `aligned` and a nested `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % NOT times

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Addition}       && (a+bi)+(c+di)=(a+c)+(b+d)i \\
& \text{Subtraction}    && (a+bi)-(c+di)=(a-c)+(b-d)i \\
& \text{Multiplication} &&
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    z\cdot w &= r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\cdot k(\cos\psi+i\sin\psi) \\
             &= rk\cos(\theta+\psi)+i\sin(\theta+\psi)
    \end{aligned} \\
& \text{Division}       &&
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{z}{w} &= \frac{r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}{k(\cos\psi+i\sin\psi)} \\
                &= \frac {r}{k}[\cos(\theta-\psi)+i\sin(\theta-\psi)]
    \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Some notable points:

1. `times` is obsolete, better using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`;
2. none of your `\left` and `\right` is useful, rather they're all *harmful* to spacing;
3. I changed the * into a middle dot;
4. I added the missing line for the multiplication;
5. Lowering “Multiplication” and “Division” to the middle of the two lines would make the text ambiguous (experiment the difference when you remove the two `[t]` positional arguments).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for telling me about "times" and "\left" issues too.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `\phantom` to align the second row for your `Division` title:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l l }
  Addition       & $(a + bi) + (c + di) = (a + c) + (b + d)i$ \\[\jot]
  Subtraction    & $(a + bi) - (c + di) = (a - c) + (b - d)i$ \\[\jot]
  Multiplication & $z \times w = r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta ) \times k (\cos \psi + i \sin \psi )$ \\[\jot]
  Division       & $\frac{z}{w} = \frac{r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)}{k (\cos \psi + i \sin \psi)}$ \\
                 & $\phantom{\frac{z}{w}} = \frac{r}{k} [\cos (\theta - \psi) + i \sin (\theta - \psi)]$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about \phantom, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

with `array` and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % NOT times

\begin{document}
\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Addition}       & (a+bi)+(c+di)=(a+c)+(b+d)i \\
\text{Subtraction}    & (a+bi)-(c+di)=(a-c)+(b-d)i \\
\text{Multiplication} & z\cdot w = r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\cdot k(\cos\psi+i\sin\psi) \\
\text{Division}       & \begin{aligned}[t]
\frac{z}{w} &= \frac{r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}{k(\cos\psi+i\sin\psi)} \\
            &= \frac {r}{k}\bigl[\cos(\theta-\psi)+i\sin(\theta-\psi)\bigr]
                        \end{aligned}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You beat to just this answer by a couple of minutes. :-)

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much. it looks like there's a lot of competition :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that employs a combination of `array` and `aligned` environments. The second column is defined to use `\displaystyle` math mode automatically.

Relative to the previously-posted answers, this one uses a math font (MathTime Professional 2, aka `mtpro2`) which is (a) consistent with the document's text font (Times Roman) and (b) is generously spaced, more similar to Computer Modern than most other Times Roman-based math fonts. Note that while the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge, its `lite` subset -- which is all that's needed for the present example -- is indeed free.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}  % 'times' is ancient...
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} L M @{}}
Addition       & (a+bi) + (c+di) = (a+c) + (b+d)i  \\ \addlinespace
Subtraction    & (a+bi) - (c+di) = (a-c) + (b-d)i  \\ \addlinespace
Multiplication & \begin{aligned}[t]
                    z\cdot w &= r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)\cdot
                                k(\cos\psi +i\sin\psi) \\
                             &= rk[\cos(\theta+\psi)+i\sin(\theta+\psi)]    
                 \end{aligned} \\ \addlinespace
Division       & \begin{aligned}[t]
                   \frac{z}{w} &= \frac{r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}
                                       {k(\cos\psi + i\sin\psi)} \\
                               &= (r/k) [\cos(\theta-\psi) +i\sin (\theta-\psi)] 
                 \end{aligned}   \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```